# Why does UDP socket sending takes such long time in Micropython?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

with Rapsberry pi Pico + W5100s(Ethernet) + micropython 1.18

i am making a program sending and receving data by UDP.

i print the time before it send and after it sent..

The result below

238590
239111

the time difference is 521ms

is there anyway to reduce the time?

i've trid to use uasyncio for sending part.. but results are same.

please help me to reduce the sending time.

tks

---

MicroPython Code

```
from machine import Pin, SPI, UART
import network
import usocket as socket
import ubinascii, uhashlib
import gc
import time
import _thread

UDPServer_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

receivedData = ''

GPIOThreadRunning = True

commandType = 0

CAMID = 1
isLED = 0
Protocal = 2

def init_ethernet(ip_address, subnet, gateway, dns, socket_port):
    
    global RS485UART, GPIOThreadRunning

    spi = SPI(0, 2_000_000, mosi=Pin(19), miso=Pin(16), sck=Pin(18))
    nic = network.WIZNET5K(spi, Pin(17), Pin(20))

    nic.ifconfig((ip_address, subnet, gateway, dns))

    while not nic.isconnected():
        pass
    

    UDPServer_socket.bind((ip_address, socket_port))
    
    print(f'Listening UDP on {ip_address} port {socket_port}')
    
    ZoomSppedForT1Bytes = b''
    
    while True:
        gc.collect()
        print("Waiting UDP....")
        #udp receive data from client
        data, addr = UDPServer_socket.recvfrom(30) ## buffer size is 1024 bytes
        

        commandType = 0
        
        

        if len(data) > 0 :
                                    
            #cmdArr = Commands(data)
            cmdArr = bytearray(data)
            
            print('command from controller : ' + BytesToHexString(cmdArr))
            
            
            
            if cmdArr[:4] == b'\xff\xff\xff\xff':
                break

            
            

            if cmdArr[:4] == b'\x02\x00\x00\x01':
                
                
                #reset sequence number
                replyHeader = b'\x02\x01\x00\x01'
                replySeq = cmdArr[4:8]
                replyCommand = cmdArr[8:]


                print(time.ticks_ms())
                UDPServer_socket.sendto(replyHeader+replySeq+replyCommand, addr)
                print(time.ticks_ms())

            else:
                pass
                
            
            
           
    GPIOThreadRunning = False   
    
    time.sleep(1)
def BytesToHexString(data):
    return ubinascii.hexlify(data).decode()


def GPIOThread():
    global GPIOThreadRunning, RS485UART, CAMID

    isLED = 0
    
    SwitchPin = Pin(1, Pin.IN)
    
    time.sleep(1)
    print('GPIO Thread is start')
    

    while GPIOThreadRunning:
        
        
        #if isLED == 0:
        #    STATUSLED.value(1)
        #    time.sleep(0.01)
        if isLED == 1:
            STATUSLED.value(0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            STATUSLED.value(1)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        elif isLED == 2:
            STATUSLED.value(0)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            STATUSLED.value(1)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        
        #switcher push:1, un-push:0
        SwitcherValue = SwitchPin.value()
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    _thread.start_new_thread(GPIOThread, ())
  
    
    ip_address = '192.168.0.201'
    subnet = '255.255.255.0'
    gateway = '192.168.0.1'
    dns = '8.8.8.8'
    

    socket_port = 52381

    init_ethernet(ip_address, subnet, gateway, dns, socket_port)
    
    print('#########################################')
    print('here end of code')
```

'''

## **

## the result is **

```
> Listening UDP on 192.168.0.201 port 52381
> 
> Waiting UDP....
> 
> command from controller : 020000010000000001
> 
> 238590
> 
> 239111
> 
> Waiting UDP....
```